# How to fetch first 1000 documents that don't have certain field?

Tags: c#, .net, mongodb, linq, mongodb-.net-driver

Say, I have collection `People`. How should I fetch first 1000 documents that **doesn't have** a field `Phone`? As I understand, I should use `$exists` however I cannot understand how to use it from .NET driver and there is next to no info on that topic on the internet. Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume your Model Class is `Model` and colelction name is "Model".

```
var coll = db.GetCollection<Model>("Model");
var ret = coll.Find(Builders<Model>.Filter.Exists(d => d.Phone, false))
              .Limit(1000)
              .ToList();
```

With ToList you will get already loaded list, sometimes it's better to use ToEnumerable and have enumerable to iterate.